# Emacs hangs the network when C-g or M-x keyboard-quit, what does keyboard-quit do behind the scenes?

Tags: quitting, networking, frozen-emacs

Working with emacs on a new RH8 network accessed from a remote windows machine using VNC.
Emacs is running on RH8.
Starting from emacs -Q
when I perform C-g or M-x keyboard-quit emacs hangs and the network seems to hang.
I no longer have access to the other programs or the terminal, access and the screen is frozen.
I have to quit out of the double hop windows virtual session I am in to regain control.

My question is:
**What does keyboard-quit do behind the scenes that could trigger this behavior**?
Bonus points for how to debug this.

For example when running M-x keyboard-quit does emacs:

- Check something external to emacs?
- Allocate or releasing memory?
- Perform garbage collection?
- Write out history or logging?
- Try to ping some ip?
- Something else like this?

I have repeated this experiment with versions (not all versions) of emacs from emacs 26.1 thru emacs 29. Don't think it has anything to do with the emacs version.

I don't think its something else grabbing the key binding; can repeat the issue just by starting from emacs -Q, then M-x keyboard-quit, and the session is hung up.

Not loading libraries/packages between emacs -Q and M-x keyboard-quit.
Based on this, I don't think its anything I am doing with in my config (.emacs file).

Some of the versions of emacs were build locally in my home dir.  Some were installed my someone with superuser and RH installer.

When I run emacs -Q, there are no messaged displayed in the terminal.  At that time all seems well.

The lockup lasts about 30s-1min for emacs -Q.
If I launch with my full emacs configuration the lockup lasts longer.